# Pascal ABC (while(a / 10) error)

Tags: winforms, pascal, pascalabc.net

Как, например, число 1841 - разбить на десятки? Потому что я записываю его потом в массив [1,8,4,1].

В ABC если я пишу в условии `while(a / 10) && if(a / 10)`, он говорит следующее

> Нельзя преобразовать тип real к boolean

Цель всего этого – узнать сколько будет цифр, дабы потом создать под него определенный размер массива, дабы потом вызвать `setlength(mass, i);`.

Также, как можно пофиксить следующее

> Ошибка времени выполнения: Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для Int32.

Получаю эту ошибку, когда я ввожу 10ти значное число. Пробовал ставить :Longint, но увы =\

Код ABC

```
while(true) do
  begin
    if (a / 10) then
      begin
        a := a / 10;
        i += 1
      end
    else
    begin
      break;
      end;
  end;
```

Тоже самое на С++

```cpp
else {
    while (a / 10) {
        abc.push_back(a % 10);
        a /= 10;
    }
    abc.push_back(a % 10);
}
```

Comment: 'a /10' это арифметическая операция. Что вы пытаетесь проверить?

Comment: вторую проблему вы решали в верном направлении- надо сменить тип данных на соответствующий Int64 . просто где-то недорешали

Comment: в вашем вопросе два разных по сути. Надо задавать два разных вопроса. Еще посмотрите как вы привели код. Откуда выдернут второй кусок? что значит ++ между кусками кода? Текст в начале перегружен смайликами, фрагменты кода не выделены ``

Comment: @4per 2 блок кода я имел ввиду то как сделал на с++ )) В программу (1 TextBox ) я ввожу число без разделения (987654) после я это число записываю в массив для сортировки но т.к (987654) является единым числом поэтому чтоб разделить его. я произвожу следующее действие - это число делю на 10 и записываю по очереди в массив. Но размер массива я указываю вручную и следовательно могу ввести только определенное количество данных в него... я прошу вас помочь с тем чтоб когда я ввожу в TextBox число например (4321) программа видела что у нас в TextBox 4 значения и следовательно массив будет для 4 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то у вас из контекста вырвано…
Если хотите, можете разобрать число на цифры математическими операциями:

```
  begin
    var N := 987654;
    var a : array of integer;
    SetLength(a, N.ToString.Length);
    var index := 0;
    repeat
      a[index] := N mod 10;
      index += 1;
      N := N div 10;
    until N = 0;
    a.Println;
  end.
```

А можно проще:

```
  begin
    var N := 987654;
    var a := N.ToString.ToCharArray.Select(i->StrToInt(i));
    a.Println;
  end.
```

P.S. Отсортировать массив можно всего лишь одним оператором „a.Sort“…

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while(a / 10)
> ```

Во-первых, на самом деле тут имеется в виду не вещественное деление, а целочисленное:

```
while (a div 10)
```

Во-вторых, возможно, что паскаль не умеет приводить числа к логическим значениям, в таком случае

```
while (a div 10 <> 0)
```

или

```
until (a div 10 = 0)
```

А если известно, что число `a` положительно, то всё упрещается до

```
while (a > 9)
```